# How can I install a package with setup.py provided, within a virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have [goose](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) installed system-wide, but not in a virtualenv I have been working on

```
$ python -c "import goose" #ok
(venv)$ python -c "import goose" #not ok
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named goose
```

The setup instructions say

```
mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages goose
git clone https://github.com/grangier/python-goose.git
cd python-goose
pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py install
```

How can I install it within my existing virtualenv `venv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the setup instructions, but activate your virtualenv (`workon venv` or `. venv/bin/activate`) before calling `pip` or `python`.

Comment: Indeed, but if he followed the instructions to the letter he installed goose in *another* virtualenv called `goose` instead of there.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkvirtualenv goose_project
workon goose_project
git clone https://github.com/grangier/python-goose 
cd python-goose/
python setup.py install
```

and to verify installation

```
pip freeze | grep "goose"
goose-extractor==1.0.22
```